# Getting "lately reading sequential formatted external IO" when trying to run a fortran program using python .subprocess

Tags: python, powershell, fortran, subprocess

currently im trying to automate the process of running a fortran-based program that's already in .exe file using python subprocess. The program can be run through powershell and that's what i'm trying to do to automate using python subprocess. The program required multiple input, where you input a data, then enter, and do it numerous time. I'm trying to automate this process by importing an excel file using pandas, then loop through all the row/column as input to the software, where i press enter after each time i input the data. In the powershell, after you run the program, you only have to type the data directly using the keyboard and press enter, and do it continuously like i explained before.

Please understand that I'm very new to the python subprocess program, and know a little to nothing about software programming, let alone an old language like fortran. From what i read in many python subprocess tutorial, here's what i need to do to run a program with subprocess and make an input to the program. Here's what a simplified program looks like. I simplified it because it gives me an error from this simple program only.

```
    process = subprocess.Popen(program_path, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.communicate(input=input_value.encode())
    process.wait()
```

The code above gives me an error. Even if i only run the first line, that i understand is only the step to connect to the program, even before inputting to it, gives me an error as shown below.

```
 fmt: end of file
apparent state: unit 5 (unnamed)
last format: (a)
lately reading sequential formatted external IO
      1 [sig] wain12 21564 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to wain12.exe.stackdump
```

I've tried to ask ChatGPT about this error, but it said that the error is correlated with the expected input from this fortran-based program, and i need to find the software documentation for me to understand the input. Sadfully, the software was developed very long ago, and the documentation is nowhere to be found.

Is there any way for me to solve this? because before i even tried to give an input to the program (only running the first line) it already gave me the error. Any suggestion and answer will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit:

After consulting in the comment, i think i should try to elaborate it even more and showing the result of the code and how the program run.

first, i've been succesfully run the software using `subprocess.run`, it shows in the code below:

```
process = subprocess.run("D:\PGE\~CIP\code\wain12.exe")
```

it runs succesfully and i can give input to the to the software through the terminal, as shown below.
[result of using run and the terminal asking for input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytaGq.png)

now, if i use the `subprocess.Popen', it will resulting like the image shown

```
process = subprocess.Popen("D:\PGE\~CIP\code\wain12.exe")
```

[Showing the same software header but can't give input in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRnM0.png)

It shows the same software header, but the terminal don't ask for input, unlike when i use 'subprocess.run'. From what i understand, this is the part where i should add `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` so i can give input to the software run through terminal. But, if i run the code below

```
process = subprocess.Popen("D:\PGE\~CIP\code\wain12.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

it shows the same error i've shown above

```
d:/PGE/~CIP/Code/test.py

 ICELANDIC  WATER  CHEMISTRY  GROUP

 Program WAIN, version 1.2,  April 2002.

 Prompts the user for input data to the program WATCH
 and writes it to the file WATCH.IN


 Output file (default watch.in)  : fmt: end of file
apparent state: unit 5 (unnamed)
last format: (a)
lately reading sequential formatted external IO
      2 [sig] wain12 17148 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to wain12.exe.stackdump
```

sorry if i can't give any diagnostics print because it's only 1 line of code. Hope these explanation can give more insights on my current problem

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]. You get an error from a Fortran code so you should show the Fortran code. Try  simple debugging techniques, such as inserting diagnosting `print` statements to find out where the error happens.

Comment: The ChatGPT answer is basically correct. The Fortran code is reading some data. You have to provide the data in the right format. If the program runs correctly on the command line, you have to provide the same data through the pipe.

Comment: You can try to create a different simpler program in a different programming language you know to see if the data you send through the pipe is what is expected.

Comment: Sorry, but i think my problem is not in any way related to any fortran coding, so i can't realy provide a fortran code, because there isn't any, theres only an exe file that i know is running on fortran., May i conclude that there is no other way to give an input in a background process aside from knowing what the input format should be? I must say that i'm new in any of this, so can you elaborate more what you mean by providing the same data through the pipe? and i don't really understand other programming language aside from python, so can you give me an advice on what language i should try?

Comment: The program expects some data in some format. You have to provide the data in the exact format as required. It is as simple as that. **IF** (but please confirm) you know which format works from the command line you can try to provide the same data using the pipe. If it fails, the problem is somewhere in using the pipe. For testing the pipe you can use any language you want. If you know Python, use Python.

Comment: But how do i know the exact format? in command line i only type it directly using keyboard. If you see in my code, i haven't tried to input anything to the program, when i run the `subprocess.Popen` (first line of code), the resulting error come up. So i can't really try to change any format. Or does the error happens because of the nature of the `subprocesss.Popen` can't interact with this fortran-based program? how do i know which format works for the command line if i only type my data directly when interacting with the command line? thank you, sorry if my questions is too basic

Comment: The error is end of file on unit 5. Unit 5 is the standard input. It means that the standard input file ends unexpectedly. When I try your Python code on Linux with a test executable (created in Fortran) it works well. It does ultimately get the same error message when the input ends and the executable expects more, *but it happens in `communicate`, **not** in `Popen`*. Please double check where it actually crashes. Add some diagnostic print statements into your Python code and show the full output. Also, I really do suggest to take the tour and read the other links I gave in my first comment.

Comment: Thank you for giving me links on how to improve my question. I've given more detailed explanation on my problem and the full output of the python code, hope it will give you more insights on the problem i face.  It's definitely not on the 'communicate' part, because I haven't even put it into my code.

Comment: Please, do not use pictures for text information. Certainly not for error messages. They should be searchable and copy-able. Please double check that it really crashes where you think it does. Either remove all commands after `Popen`, or better, insert a print statement with some message between `Popen` and `communicate`.

Comment: Once again, thank you for reminding me, im sorry it's my very first time asking question here. I've made the edit, i have to show the result of the code as image to show that there's some differences when running using `subprocess.run` and `subprocess.Popen', where in `subprocess.run` the terminal is asking for input and the software runs like it should be. And yes, i only put the `subprocess.Popen` part in the code, there's only one line, and i have deleted the `communicate` part, and it still shows the same error. I really appreciate if you could give me advice on how to deal with it. Thanks

Comment: you said that you tried to run it with a test executable created in Fortran, but it doesn't work in my Fortran-based program, so may i assume that my program required different input from your executable file? But i still think that the error is on how i use the 'subprocess.Popen', because like i said i haven't put any input, i haven't use the 'communicate' part, only the 'subprocess.Popen' and it shows the error. Is there any thoughts on this?

Comment: No, such conclusion is not warranted. I only made a simple program that echoes the input to see if it gets past the Popen. It did in my case, but it is a different operating system. I have nothing more to suggest. You can try this program yourself, but you would need a Fortran compiler https://pastebin.com/YsVxRWKj